# ANTLR4 target file names

Tags: antlr4

For the [TypeScript ANTLR target](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts#antlr4ts---typescriptjavascript-target-for-antlr-4) that Sam and I have been working on, I would like to have the code generation tool create a single typescript file to hold all the classes generated from a named grammar input.   Is this output file structure going to be hard?

So for example, I'd like **Expr.g4** -> **Expr.g4.ts**.   That one file TypeScript file could contain named exports for `{ExprLexer, ExprParser,` and `ExprListener}` classes, visitor code if requested, maybe even some loose factory functions etc.

I've been looking into the source code under [tool/src/org/antlr/v4/codegen](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/codegen) to find out how the number and names of the output files are determined, in particular finding [CodeGenPipeline.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/codegen/CodeGenPipeline.java),  This class works in conjunction with the language-specific target class, but the pipeline has a lot (perhaps too much) knowledge of possible output files built into it.   None of what I see in CodeGenPipeline.java seems well matched to my 1:1 input-to-output file model.

It seems like the knowledge of what files should be generated for a given language target *should* come from the **language.stg** file if possible, but I can't find any evidence that approach has been implemented.   Can anyone fill me in on any reasons that approach can't hasn't been tried or worked?